# Inserting tags in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to make a comment system with multi tags person like facebook. And don't know how to insert these tags in mysql

I'm using this plugins http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/, but it show just how to tag persons not how ton insert them in mysql.

regards

Comment: Let's start at the beginning... Do you know how to connect to MySQL from PHP?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes i know very well mysql and php. The problem with this plugin is that i don't know how to detect each tags from box comment and insert it in mysql by clicking in button send

Comment: Post your attempt to do this in your question.  If you not yet made an attempt, you should do so now.